# How to handle data duplication in c#

Tags: sql-server, database

While clicking on `add` button data is saved in database but after 2-3 times refresh data in database there 2-4 copies of same data is shown.

How to get to fix this?

```
String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblBrands values('" + txtBrandName.Text + "')", con);
  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  txtBrandName.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Your code clearly inserts data and it has no provisions or checks to prevent duplicates. Either *don't call the code using the same data more than once*, or if you can't avoid that, add code to *check for existing data before inserting new data*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to solve in SQL (assuming from your tags) you could check before inserting using:

```
if not exists (select * from tblBrands where ...)
```

Build your where clause based on your criteria - what would you consider duplicate entry

More info on `exists` in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)